# Clarifying Calculation of Induced Mappings (Pullback) in Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, pullback

I am reading *Mathematical Analysis* by Andrew Browder and am confused in his calculating the meaning of $\mathbf{f^\ast},$ the "induced mapping" or pullback of $\mathbf{f^\ast}.$ Here's his definition:

Suppose that $V$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^m$, $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ and $\mathbf{f}$ is a smooth map of $V$ into $U$. Then $\mathbf{f}$ induces a map $\mathbf{f^{\ast}}: \Omega^r(U) \rightarrow \Omega^r(V)$ defined by

$$(\mathbf{f^{\ast}}\omega)_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_r)=\omega_{\mathbf{f(p)}}(\mathbf{f'(p)v}_1, \ldots \mathbf{f'(p)v}_r).$$
Then he writes
$$(\mathbf{f^{\ast}}dx^I)_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_r)=dx^I(\mathbf{f'(p)v}_1, \ldots \mathbf{f'(p)v}_r)={(df^{i_1} \wedge \ldots \wedge df^{i_r})}_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{v}_1 \ldots \mathbf{v}_r).$$
Why does the second equality hold?

Comment: Basically since $f^*$ commutes with $d$ and distribute with wedge product. You don't need the second term, just write $f^* dx^I = f^* dx^{i_1} \wedge f^* dx^{i_2} \wedge \cdots \wedge f^* dx^{i_r} = df^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge df^{i_r}$ since $f\circ x^{i_k} = f^{i_k}$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense. The problem is that the author makes this claim before talking about $\mathbf{f}^{*}(\omega \wedge \eta) = (\mathbf{f}^{*} \omega) \wedge (\mathbf{f}^{*}{\eta})$, so how does one "see" this equality without knowledge of this?